# Dual boot windows 8.1 and Ubuntu?(Ubuntu preinstalled) SSD & HDD System76 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-8, ssd

I have a system76 laptop (Kudu Professional).  It has an i7 core w/ 8gb of RAM. There are two drives:  a 250 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD.  The Kudu came with Ubuntu pre-installed(version 15.04).

I looked at other similar questions but they seem to have windows pre-installed on their laptops while mine is pre-installed with Ubuntu.

Also many ask for Windows 7 while I am asking for windows 8.1.  There has been all this fuss about windows 8.1 having secure boot and that it is more difficult to dual boot than previous windows versions.  That is why I am asking this question.

My question is:  How would I dual boot Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1?

My college requires me to have windows as some software is only compatible with windows.  I looked at many videos and read many posts, but I am confused. I am starting college in the fall and am worried that I will not be able to access important homework due to the requirement of windows on some software as stated above. (CS major)

Also, would it be better to partition the SSD half for windows 8.1 and half for Ubuntu?

How much should I partition for windows to play games as well?

Where does the HDD apply to and how to access it with SSD used for the operating systems?

IMPORTANT AND LAST QUESTIONS: With Ubuntu pre-installed, would I need to buy Windows 8.1?  If so, is there anyway to get it for free and burn it to a disk just in case something goes wrong?

I am excited to do this and harness the power of the Kudu!
If you can help me through this or link a video that applies to my version and time frame, it would be much appreciated.

update 2:  I am back.

Comment: I can help you quite a bit but I need to know specifics about your hardware to know if some version of raid should be implemented.  You have quite a laptop in your hands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) ***NOTE:*** It's *critically* important that you determine your boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI) before proceeding. In Ubuntu, look for the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory. If it's present, you've installed Ubuntu in EFI mode; if it's absent, you're in BIOS mode. You ***MUST*** install Windows in the same mode.

Comment: You have to buy Windows, it is not free, but you college may offer discounts. Check with college bookstore or CS department. Post this to see current configuration. `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @RodSmith efi is not present in that directory.  This must mean that it is in BIOS mode.